# Sklearn gridsearch with MLP where to put the random state?

Tags: scikit-learn, grid-search, random-seed

So I did the following:

```
   MLP = MLPRegressor()
      parameter_space = {
'hidden_layer_sizes': [(32,), (32,16), (32,16,8), (32,16,8,4), (32,16,8,4,2), (32,32), (32,32,32), (32,32,32,32), (32,32,32,32,32), (16,8,4,2)],
'activation': ['relu'],
'solver': ['adam'],
'learning_rate_init': [1, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001,0.0001,0.00001],
'max_iter': [5000],
'shuffle': [True, False],
'random_state': [0],
'early_stopping': [True, False],
'n_iter_no_change': [50],
}

gs_MLP = GridSearchCV(estimator = MLP, param_grid= parameter_space, cv = 7, n_jobs = -1) 
gs_MLP_fit = gs_MLP.fit(X, y)
gs_MLP.score(X,y)
```

And I noticed that whenever I change the order within the hidden_layer_size it gives different answers. First it said (16,8,4,2) and when I put (16,8,4,2) at end it said (32,32,32,32) is the best.

I assume this has to do with the random_state? Do I have to put it in MLPRegressor() instead? As in MLPRegressor(random_state = 0)